# Not able to create cache in Windows Server Appfabric

Tags: caching, appfabric

I am getting "ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified Cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account on the cluster and that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Retry later.)" error when trying to create a datacache in appfabric. The error comes when in "DataCacheFactory dcf = new DataCacheFactory(config);" statement.

P.S. :-

1. I have given Grant_CacheAllowedClientAccount to myself.
2. I have started the cache by "Start-CacheCluster"

Comment: What configuration are you attempting to pass in? Also, what does your client configuration look like?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, actually i did not configure appfabric properly :P